# How to set a different namespace for child helm charts?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When you install a chart with a child chart that doesn't specify a namespace, Helm will use the one specified on command line via `--namespace`. Is it possible to override this flag for a specific child chart?

For example if I have chart A which depends on chart B and I specify `--namespace foo`, I want to be able to customize the resources of chart B to be installed into some other namespace `bar` instead of `foo`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Update 2:
Helm 3 added support for multi namespaces https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2060

Update 1:
If a resource template specifies a `metadata.namespace`, then it will be installed in that namespace. For example, if I have a pod with `metadata.namespace: x` and I run `helm install mychart --namespace y`, that pod will be installed in x. I guess you could use regular helm templates with the namespace to parameterize it.

Original answer:

> We do not plan on fully supporting multi-namespaced releases until Helm 3.0 
>   https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/2060#issuecomment-306847365

As a workaround, you install for each namespace individually using `--skip-dependencies` or with [dependency conditions](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/charts.md#tags-and-condition-fields-in-requirementsyaml)

Comment: Thanks for sharing `Update 2`. I am still unable to work out how helm 3 solve the problem of deploying child charts in a different namespace. Do you mind sharing an example?

Comment: I am not sure if helm 3 also solves this problem - at least it's not very clear if it solves the problem that the OP asked. Without specifying the metadata.namespace (which was supported earlier also), how do sub charts get installed into their own namespaces?

Comment: One of the helm maintainers recommends helmfile to do this - https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5358#issuecomment-628920908

Comment: It's not the thing questioner wanted.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have different charts then you can use [helmfile](https://github.com/helmfile/helmfile) to achieve this.

**Step 1**:
create the following folder.

```
my-awesome-infrastructure/
  helm
  helmfile
  helmfile.yaml
```

Where helm and helmfile are the binary executables.

**Step 2**: install the helm diff plugin which is needed used helmfile.

```bash
helm plugin install https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff
```

**Step 3**: declare your charts in the `helmfile.yaml`.

```yaml
helmBinary: ./helm

repositories:
  - name: ingress-nginx
    url: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
  - name: bitnami
    url: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
releases:
  - name: nginx-ingress
    namespace: nginx-ingress
    createNamespace: true
    chart: ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
    version: ~4.1.0
  - name: jupyterhub
    namespace: jupyterhub
    createNamespace: true
    chart: bitnami/jupyterhub
    version: ~1.1.12
  - name: metrics-server
    namespace: metrics-server
    createNamespace: true
    chart: bitnami/metrics-server
    version: ~5.11.9
```

Step 4: run helmfile to deploy all charts.

```bash
./helmfile apply
```

In the above example, you are deploying three separate charts to three separate namespaces.
Under the covers, `helmfile` will run `helm` install separately and create separate releases.