# Kubernetes service deploying in default namespace instead of defined namespace using Helm

Tags: kubernetes, environment, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy my microservice on a Kuberenetes cluster in 2 different environment dev and test. And I am using helm chart to deploy my Kubernetes service. I am using Jenkinsfile to deploy the chart. And inside Jenkinsfile I added helm command within the stage like the following ,

```
stage ('helmchartinstall')
                {
                    steps
                    {
                        sh 'helm upgrade --install kubekubedeploy --namespace test pipeline/spacestudychart'
                    }
                }
             }
```

Here I am defining the `--namespace` test parameter. But when it deploying, it showing the console output with default namespace. I already created namespaces test and prod.

When I checked the Helm version, I got response like the following,

```
docker@mildevdcr01:~$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.1", 
GitCommit:"5270352a09c7e8b6e8c9593002a73535276507c0", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.0", 
GitCommit:"05811b84a3f93603dd6c2fcfe57944dfa7ab7fd0", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Have I made any mistake here for defining the namespace?

Comment: Maybe u need to create the namespace before hand. also check ur helm version is latest

Comment: the support is added in helm 3 https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2060

Comment: Did you previously deploy the kubedeploy release in a different namespace? I think helm v2 checks for the release first and ignores the namespace flag in that case.

Comment: @Blokje5 - No. first time also happening like this.

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan - If it is version problem , What I need to do here ? Do I need to upgrade my version from older into 3 ? Or any another latest version?

Comment: @Jacob make sure you are using latest helm version

Comment: also u can control the namsepace from chart template

Comment: in which NS is your Tiller deployed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely issue here is that the Chart already specifies `default` as `metadata.namespace` which in Helm 2 is not overwritten by the `--namespace` parameter.

If this is the cause a solution would be to remove the namespace specified in the `metadata.namespace` or to make it a template parameter (aka release `value`).

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51137448/1977182.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1:

```
export TILLER_NAMESPACE= your_namespace
helm upgrade -i -n release_name chart.tgz
```

Approach 2:

```
helm upgrade -i -n release_name --namespace your_namespace chart.tgz
```