# Helm subchart within a different namespace

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to install helm nested subchart in a different namespace from parent `values.yaml`.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072849/how-to-set-a-different-namespace-for-child-helm-charts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a different namespace for child helm charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072849/how-to-set-a-different-namespace-for-child-helm-charts)