# helm dependencies with different namespaces

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile, helm3

Right now, I have to install multiple helm charts in different namespaces for my product to work. I am trying to create a super helm chart in which I am planning to add the helm charts (of my tools, as mentioned above) and install them in one shot. My problem is, as these tools are in different namespaces  I am not sure where to specify the namespace key where I want that particular dependency (chart) to be installed. For e.g. if below is the Charts.yaml of my super helm chart

```
dependencies:
- name: first_chart
  version: 1.2.3
  repository: https://firstchart.repo
- name: second_chart
  version: 1.5.6
  repository: https://secondchart.repo
```

I want my first chart to be installed in namespace foo and the second chart to be installed in namespace bar.

I was looking at using conditions but I believe conditions will only take a boolean as a value.

I stumbled upon this link (https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2060)  which says the we can do it in Helm 3 but mostly on how to keep releases between different namespaces. It does not specifically answer my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a different namespace for child helm charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072849/how-to-set-a-different-namespace-for-child-helm-charts)

Comment: Helm doesn't directly support this; the helm/helm#2060 issue seems to be a little more about keeping a separate list of releases per namespace rather than one globally per cluster.  If you control the subcharts you can manually add a `namespace:` to their YAML, or tools like Helmfile or Helmsman can effectively do multiple `helm install`s with more control over their options.

Comment: Thanks David. I saw the stackoverflow link which eventually points to the one which I had pasted in my question. I guess I will take your comment to install individually.

Comment: @Seeker did you eventually find the answer to this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin way to do this with pure Helm, but there is with [helmfile](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/).

Your example as `helmfile.yaml`:

```yaml
releases:
  - name: chart1 # name of the release (helm install <...> first_chart)
    chart: repo1/first_chart
    version: 1.2.3
    namespace: foo

  - name: chart2
    chart: repo2/second_chart
    version: 1.5.6
    namespace: bar

# in case you want helmfile to automatically update repos
repositories:
  - name: repo1
    url: https://firstchart.repo
  - name: repo2
    url: https://secondchart.repo
```

Then, run:

- `helmfile sync` => run `helm install/upgrade` on all releases, or
- `helmfile apply` => same as sync, but do a diff first to only upgrade/install releases that changed

There is way more to helmfile, but this is the gist.

PS: if you struggle with values or want to have something similar to how umbrella Chart values are handled, have a look at [helmfile: a simple trick to handle values intuitively](https://community.ops.io/derlin/helmfile-a-simple-trick-to-handle-values-intuitively-50cb)

Answer (score -3):

The way I solved this for my clusters with with ArgoCD's [App of Apps](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#app-of-apps) cluster [bootstrapping](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/cluster-bootstrapping/) model. Of course, it requires that ArgoCD is install the cluster. *However, for many reasons not relevant to this answer I would highly encourage installing ArgoCD regardless of the ease of bootstrapping capabilities.*

Assuming ArgoCD is in place the structure is a single Helm chart containing templates for each of the child charts it will deploy and managed via Argo's [Application](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#applications) CRD. You will notice there is a definition as part of the CRD, `spec.destination.namespace`, which governs where the chart will be deployed.

An example Application template which governs my cert-manager chart deployment to the `cert-manager` namespace looks like:

```
{{- if .Values.certManager.enabled }}
# ref: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#applications
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: cert-manager
  # You'll usually want to add your resources to the argocd namespace.
  namespace: argocd
  # Add a this finalizer ONLY if you want these to cascade delete.
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  # The project the application belongs to.
  project: cluster-configs

  # Source of the application manifests
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/yourOrg/Helm
    targetRevision: {{ .Values.targetRevision }}
    path: charts/cert-manager-chart

    # helm specific config
    helm:
      # Helm values files for overriding values in the helm chart
      # The path is relative to the spec.source.path directory defined above
      valueFiles:
        {{- range .Values.certManager.valueFiles }}
        - {{ . }}
        {{- end }}

      # Optional Helm version to template with. If omitted it will fall back to look at the 'apiVersion' in Chart.yaml
      # and decide which Helm binary to use automatically. This field can be either 'v2' or 'v3'.
      version: v3

  # Destination cluster and namespace to deploy the application
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: cert-manager
{{- end }}
```

With a corresponding `values.yaml` file for this parent chart which may look something like the following with the path to desired value file(s) in that child chart's directory specified.

```
targetRevision: v1.11.0

certManager:
  enabled: true
  valueFiles: 
    - "values.yaml"

clusterAutoScaler:
  valueFiles: 
    - "envs/dev-account/saas/values.yaml"

clusterResourceLimits:
  valueFiles: 
    - "values.yaml"

externalDns:
  valueFiles: 
    - "envs/dev-account/saas/values.yaml"

ingressNginx:
  enabled: true
  valueFiles: 
    - "values.yaml"
```

Below is a screenshot of one of my app of apps directory to complete the example.

[image: example app of apps chart directory]