# How to get/download configured/updated values.yaml file of deployed application in ArgoCD dashbaord?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm, helm3, argocd

I have deployed an application in ArgoCD using open source helm charts(created application using using argo UI dashboard).
I have modified/added some parameters in ArgoCD UI.

I need the values.yaml file with updated data so that I can use it to deploy locally or anywhere using helm command.

The one way is to see the ArgoCD UI, and copy each parameter manually which will take lot of time since I have lot of parameters set.

Is there any easy way to download the values.yaml in argo UI or using argo CLI?

Comment: you are thinking too heavily on how helm installs work; AFAIK, there is no `argo get values <release>` like `helm get values <release>`. if you leverage Argo declaratively, then you could easily scrape this information from git

Comment: Thanks for the response @LostJon , I didn't go with declarative approach, I created the project using Argo UI, and I used open source helm charts(direct https link), modified the values file in the parameters section.

Comment: The declarative Argo [app of apps](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#app-of-apps) model is hands down the way to go. You might find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956915/2631728) helpful for how to setup.